# Unity3d: calling a web service in unity editor works, but not in standalone. Why?

Tags: unity, c#, webservice

I have this line of code:

```
   SDE3D _webService = new SDE3D();
   int result = _webService.UserLogin(txtLoginUsername.text, hashString);
```

My `UserLogin` function looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://www.something.com/UserLogin", RequestNamespace="http://www.something.com/", ResponseNamespace="http://www.something.com/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public int UserLogin(string username, string password) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("UserLogin", new object[] {
                username,
                password});
    return ((int)(results[0]));
}
```

In the Unity Editor it works well.

At runtime, in my Unity game build, it doesn't work and doesn't return any error message!

What is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use a tool like Postman to try this call outside your game and see if it works. that will also report any errors you get.,

Comment: Is it possible the app (your game) is blocked by the firewall?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say it doesn't work? Is the return value different from what was expected? Is an exception thrown? Is the code not called/triggered at all? Is the response from the web service different from what you expected? Something else entirely?

Comment: it might be a firewall issue.  I would check that the stand alone app is not blocked by the firewall